# Do you run your Sybase environment in simplex or multiplex mode

Tags: sybase, sap-iq

Evaluating a BI option for a client, wanted to check common approaches.

If the answer is 'multiplex' then a couple of additional questions

a) why does SAP insist this is neither a share-nothing, nor share-everything architecture, while the rule of - a node going down doesn't affect the cluster - implies you are running in the latter (share-everything). Unless every node is required to have a single failover

b) how complicated in your experience was the administration of a multiplex

I have run Sybase, where each instance would have a single dedicated node in multiple replication and standby configurations, but never in this "hybrid" cluster.

Comment: Which "Sybase" product is this; Adaptive Server Anywhere, Adaptive Server Enterprise, Adaptive Server IQ or something else?

Comment: Adaptive SIQ 16.0